# ItextSharp - Lowercase' is ambiguous because multiple kinds of members with this name exist in class 'List'

Tags: itext

I am using vb.net and when I try set the list lettered to lowercase

mylist.lowercase = list.lowercase

I get an error

Lowercase' is ambiguous because multiple kinds of members with this name exist in class 'List'

Comment: This sounds like a .Net question, not an iText question, doesn't it?

Comment: @mkl, its both really. VB.Net is case-insensitive and iText 5.x exposes a class with two things (a field and a constant) that only differ in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lowercase` is a [protected field](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/master/src/core/iTextSharp/text/List.cs#L123) on the `List` class so I'm pretty sure you mean the class constant [`LOWERCASE`](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/master/src/core/iTextSharp/text/List.cs#L113).

For historical and back-compatibility reasons the VB.Net language is case-*insensitive* however the rest of CLR is case-*sensitive* so you have to be conscious of this.

Anyway, when using that specific field you'll run into a conflict so your safest bet is to just use the field's value of `True` in its place. If this bugs you you can also waste a bunch of extra CPU cycles and jump into reflection but I wouldn't recommend it:

```
''Bad code but works
mylist.lowercase = GetType(iTextSharp.text.List).GetField("LOWERCASE").GetValue(Nothing)
```

**EDIT**

From the comments I now see that it is the left side that is causing you problems. Just use the `IsLowercase` property instead:

```
mylist.IsLowercase = True
```

Comment: If I use mylist.lowercase = true, I get the same error.